# How do I use Drop Shadows in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am attempting to use the code from [here](https://snack.expo.io/S1NK7dxbr) in my own code.

I've copied the code vertabim into a section of my project.

```
<View>
   <View style={{
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderRadius: 20,
                borderColor: '#ddd',
                borderBottomWidth: 0,
                shadowColor: '#000',
                shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
                shadowOpacity: 0.8,
                shadowRadius: 40,
                elevation: 3,
                width: 120,
                height: 150,
                overflow: "visible",
                }}>
                <Text>Mine</Text>
   </View>
</View>
```

The example code shows a result like this

[image]

In my code I see this on Android. The box is really fat and opaque.

[image]

And on my iPhone I see this. No shadow box at all.

[image]

Can someone help me here? How do I get this to work on both platforms?
I'm very confused

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce how it looks on your end. Could you share your `package.json` file, maybe it's a version thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've added some styles to your code. Have a look at this.

```js
<View style={{
  flex: 1,
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
}}>
  <View style={{
    borderRadius: 20,
    borderColor: '#000',
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 12 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.99,
    shadowRadius: 16,
    elevation: 24,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 200,
    height: 230
  }}>
    <Text>Mine</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

It looks like

[image]